# Как лучше читается проверка на не пустую коллекцию?

Tags: java, коллекции

Интересно, как грамотнее писать проверку на то, что коллекция не пустая, следуя принципу чистого кода?

```
if(!col.isEmpty())
```

Или

```
if(col.size() > 0)
```

Или

```
if(col.get(0) != null)
```

Коварный восклицательный знак можно не заметить, однако на enSO где-то читал, что так лучше читается, но мне кажется, что наиболее читаем второй вариант.

Так, как все-таки лучше?

Comment: `Коварный восклицательный знак можно не заметить` - ты программируешь без восклицательных знаков вообще?)

Comment: Нет, я их, конечно, использую, например if(!stoped), но в случаях когда If(!getBlah().blah().blah().blah().blah().blah().isEmpty()) его и правда можно не заметить

Comment: if(!col.isEmpty()) только так

Comment: `If(!getBlah().blah().blah().blah().blah().blah().isEmpty()) его и правда можно не заметить` - в таком случае надо программисту руки отрывать, чтоб так не писал

Comment: Третий вариант вообще не эквивалентен

Comment: Можете писать `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(col)`, чтобы не путаться. Так ещё и на null проверять не нужно.

Comment: @ahgpoug все коллекции хранят свой размер, так что вызов метода `size()` настолько быстр, насколько быстра операция `return this.size`. Исключение составляет `ConcurrentHashMap`, которая хранит размер каждого страйпа и суммирует их в момент вызова `size()`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, строго говоря, они не обязаны. Думаю, существуют коллекции, которые не знают своего размера, пока их не спросят, потому что это сложно.

Comment: @vp_arth наверняка где-то есть такие коллекции, но не в JCF.

Comment: В 1.2, вполне вероятно, были) Но лень проверять. В современной реализации была бы непростительна линейная сложность для size)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `if(col.size() > 0)`
>   и 
>     `if(col.get(0) != null)`

вообще не вариант.

`if(!col.isEmpty())` больше подходит, но как вы верно заметили оператор `"!"` часто можно не заметить, потому что наш мозг плохо работает с отрицанием. Из-за этого иногда трудно будет найти ошибку в коде.

Вы говорите о чистом коде. В таких ситуациях я часто, даже почти всегда пользуюсь рефакторингом, а точнее извлекаю это условие в метод (Extract method) и называю метод в зависимости от того какой коллекцией пользуюсь:

Например,

```
if(!children.isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```

`!children.isEmpty()` ивлекаю в метод `hasChildren()`.

```
if (hasChildren()) {
    // do something
}

private boolean hasChildren() {
    return !children.isEmpty();
}
```

Такой код лучше читается и не путает другого программиста который будет работать с вашим кодам.

Вот еще варианты: 
`!orders.isEmpty()` -> `hasOrders()`. Если заказы пусты, значит ничего не заказывал(а).
`!playlist.isEmpty()` -> `hasPlaylist()`. Если пользователь вообще ничего не добавлял(а) в плейлист, значит у него (нее) нет плейлиста.
и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, вы не указали еще вариант

```
if (col.isEmpty()) {
   return ... // результат если коллекция пуста
} else {
   ... // результат если не пуста
}
```

Во-вторых, `if(col.size() > 0)` довольно некрасивый на мой взгляд, тем более что для строк и кастомных классов он не всегда подходит. К тому же кастомные коллекции могут быстро отдавать ответ `isEmpty()` и долго `size()`.  Иметь один вариант для всех случаев предпочтительнее.

Comment: При наличии return, else is redundant

Comment: ... а `col.get(0)` вообще должно упасть на пустой коллекции

Comment: "При наличии return, else is redundant" - а это дело вкуса и стиля, по-мне так читается лучше, так как сразу видно что это два разных взаимоисключающих варианта. А если в первой ветке много кода, то нужно искать глазами return, чтобы понять это взаимоисключающие ветки или ветка дополняющая другую. Для компилятора пофиг, а для человека есть разница. Плюс есть гарантия что в будущем если добавят if'ов в первой ветке и return станет не безусловным, то компилятор ругнется, а не выполнит 2 ветку

Comment: `а это дело вкуса и стиля` - мне кажется  весь вопрос дело вкуса и стиля... и вообще решаемой задачи

Comment: @VladD, разве? Вернётся просто `null`

Comment: Во-первых, функции get в коллекции нет, она есть только в List. Во-вторых, даже в List в таком случае выпадет IndexOutOfBoundsException (см javadoc). В-третих, вы путаете с get у Map'ы, тот вернет null, но он не принимает индекс, а принимает объект-ключ, так что это тоже работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

По уму нужно использовать `col.isEmpty()`.
Плюсы тут не в производительности. Если заглянуть в исходники метода, то, скорее всего, вы сможете увидеть `return size == 0;`

Все обстоит немного иначе…
Начнем с того, что если писать код правильно и грамотно, то все классы предметной области должны взаимодействовать через их интерфейсы.
Это дает много плюсов, в т.ч. гибкость, ведь по сути, если класс А имеет дело с интерфейсом класса В, то класс А вообще ничего не знает о существовании класса В, вы можете с легкостью даже полностью заменить класс В, главное, чтобы он имплементировал те же интерфейсы.
Именно по этой причине, создавая новый экземпляр класса любой коллекции, мы приводим ее к интерфейсу `Map map = new HashMap()`. И вот тут самое интересное…

Теперь, вызывая `isEmpty()`, вы вообще-то обращаетесь к интерфейсу и вообще не привязаны  к непосредственной реализации этого метода в классе, либо к каким-либо другим методам. Посему работает все вышесказанное.

Comment: Читаемость этого ответа не соответствует best practice guideline =)

Comment: ну , простите,объяснил как умею, я не препод))

Comment: `size()` и `isEmpty()` оба методы интерфейса `Collection` :)

Comment: а в чем, собственно, противоречие